# Multiple database connection reusing entity mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multiple-databases

We have a case where we connect to different databases  environments, but the tables in each of the environment are the same.

Is there any way I can reuse the entity class for each of the environment?

I am using separate config class for each of the environment. Below is the config for one of the environment, similarly I have 4 others. The "packages" deduce which environment to connect to.

`code`java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"packages"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "OneEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "OneTransactionManager")
public class DevDataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean OneEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(OneDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(String[]{"packages"});
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource OneDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverclass);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(uName);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPass);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager OneTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(OneEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes - search on multi tenant - [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy) might be a good start.

Comment: If you do not have anything database specific (like native queries or table/column names etc.) defined in your entities, you could use them for all your database systems. It is the same whether you have the same database system with different schemas or entirely different db systems. Keep an eye on transaction handling and relationships.

Comment: Specifically (on top of what @juwil said), you'll need to use `@Transaction(transactionManager =...) ` with declarative transactions

Comment: @AndrewS, with tenants would i still be able to use entities and repositories?

Comment: @Ace - yes - only difference is where a connection points to (which depends on the tenant).

Comment: @AndrewS, I am able to relate to how you suggested to use tenancy, could you point me to a simpler example?